# how to get cmake to not transitive a property from a target to the ones this target depends on

Tags: cmake

We set DEBUG_POSTFIX for executable targets with

```
set_target_properties(<myexec> PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "-g")
```

It seems that is inherited by library targets these exec targets depend on.

is there a way to have that property set at the exec target alone, not propagate?

Comment: "It seems that is inherited by library targets these exec targets depend on." - CMake has no such "backward" propagation. So, what actually do you set? Do you set `DEBUG_POSTFIX` **property** for executable targets? Or do you set `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` **variable** (which affects only on libraries, not on executables)? Please, add to the question post some code, for make it easier to understand.

Comment: oh I see now we've had also  set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX -g)

so that's why the .so also have the -g postifx.

Comment: Confirmed. Put DEBUG_POSTFIX property on select targets and remove CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX and that works now.
What do I do to close this question?

Comment: "What do I do to close this question?" - If you feel that a question has no value for future readers (in that I agree), then you could just delete the question.